# sass not importing partials? Gulp shows error, not sure what it is?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp, partials, gulp-sass

the gulp error

```
 scss\style.scss: line 1, col 1, Unexpected '@'.  
scss\style.scss: line 3, col 1  , Unexpected '@'.
 scss\style.scss: line 4, col 1, Unexpected '@'.
  scss\style.scss: line 5, col 1, Unexpected '@'
```

scss code

```
@import "partials/custom-variables";

@import "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-compass";
@import "../bower_components/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

so it basically compiles the bootstrap files but not the custom partial. can't figure out why.

```
The gulpfile.js - 



var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var webserver = require('gulp-webserver');



 // sass compilation
 gulp.task('sass', function (){
 return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
.pipe(sass().on('error',gutil.log))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('fabmat/css')); 
 });




// watch files
gulp.task('watch', function(){
gulp.watch('src/*.js', ['minifyjs']);
gulp.watch('scss/*.scss',['sass']);
})

// default task
 gulp.task('default', ['minifyjs', 'sass','hint', 'webserver','watch']);
```

I can't post this without some text so ere is some gibberish   ugyhgjg ghchgchgv  gvgughvi jtvigcyi jgjvjgchgxchg

Comment: You should include your gulpfile.js

Comment: added my gulpfile.